# iOS UINavigationBar Becoming Corrupted After Presenting UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

In my app I have a `UITabBarController` with 4 tabs each with `UINavigationController` in it. From the root VC of one of the `UINavigationController` I push a new `UIViewController` when a user selects something from a table. From that detail view a modal view can be presented like this:

```
PlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[PlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
playerViewController.videoURL = videoURL;
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If that modal view is not presented the app functions just fine, but if I present that modal view from the pushed `IUViewController` then when that `IUViewController` is popped the `UINavigationBar` becomes corrupted and the next time a view is pushed I get this:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted UINavigationBar
```

I've checked to ensure that the detail view is not being pushed multiple times, and I can't figure out what would cause this.

Comment: Have you tried using `pushViewController` instead of `presentViewController`? Does the problem occurs?

Comment: Umang Bista, I just tried it and that does work however I need to present this view modally so that the tab and nav bar are no longer visible.

Comment: Which version of iOS you are using? Simulator or Device? [Found this link](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UIViewController-Transitions-Example/issues/5) and [this from RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9783)

Comment: Are you popping the view controller without dismissing the modal view controller first?

Comment: rdelmar No, each step is triggered by the user. First you dismiss the modal view, then press the back button on the detail view.

Comment: Hmm.... that should work fine, so it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `playerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext` before presenting the ViewController